# CCEditbox can't use copy, select paste function

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

When long press the input box it can popup the system menus (like select select All or copy select paste), but when press the menu the system keyboard was directly exit.

It seems that press on external area. Other platform(iphone4, iPad) words well. Any one meet the same issue and and found the solution for it ?